# Prevent form fields changes

Tags: forms

I have custom field on theme settings. I get default_value for that field from .info file and that's OK. I change the value of that field and submit the form and get a changed value but I do not want it. I want, after submitting form the value of that field will be changed but in that field the value will be showing the default_value from .info file. How could I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood right you should implement next steps to achieve your goal:

1. Take a look at [drupal_parse_info_file()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_parse_info_file/7) function to get a value from .info file.
2. Alter your form and set appropriate value to `#default_value` property whithin your field.